# Why is my finnhub.io request returning same response each time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, finnhub

I am making one API request for a stock price every second and getting the same response each time. When I refresh the page, I get a new response, but then it doesn't change, no matter how many times I repeat the call.

This occurs when using "finnhub"
But it changes each time when using the `polygon.io` api.
`polygon.io`, however, gives me 15 minute delayed data and won't work.

To make the request, I am using the axios `node.js` package.

```
ApiRequest = function () {
  const currentPriceURL = `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=SPY&token=` + API_KEY;

  axios.get(currentPriceURL)
    .then(response => {

      // record price of SPY
      var price = response.data.c;
      console.log("price= " + price);
    }).catch(error => console.error(`Error: ` + error));
} // end of ApiRequest function

// repeat every second
let DisplaySpyPrice_Timer = setInterval(ApiRequest, 1000);
```

Why does one API require a page refresh to update, while the other does not?

Comment: page refresh to update? is this not a node.js script then?

Answer (score 0):

Not your code problem, the `polygon.io` did not update data.

I tested your code with toggle switching symbol.
It's price change every time.

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const API_KEY = '<your API Key>'
let even = true
ApiRequest = function () {
    const stockSymbol = (even) ? 'SPY' : 'AAPL'
    const currentPriceURL = `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${stockSymbol}&token=` + API_KEY;
    even = !even;

    axios.get(currentPriceURL)
        .then(response => {

            // record price of SPY
            var price = response.data.c;
            console.log("price= " + price);
        }).catch(error => console.error(`Error: ` + error));
} // end of ApiRequest function

// repeat every second
let DisplaySpyPrice_Timer = setInterval(ApiRequest, 1000);
```

Result

```
$node get-stock-price.js
price= 396.38
price= 146.71
price= 396.38
price= 146.71
price= 396.38
price= 146.71
```